# Window 8.1 freeze after wakeup from sleep and hibernate

Tags: windows, windows-8, freeze, sleep, hibernate

My Windows froze after wake up from sleep mode or resume from hibernate mode. Before this happen I was using it fine.

It's up for a few second and then freeze (mouse/keyboard don't work, heard of white noise, focus cursor stay still). Sometimes this happen when starting up Windows, it’s a black screen with a frozen mouse (sometime not with mouse). Have to power off and reboot to turn it back to normal.

I'm moving a lot, so I have to use the hibernate mode to save my works, so this problem is annoying me so much.

I searched the internet to resolve it:

I had try to use powercfg command, turnoff wakeup mode on devices, change power plan setting, reduce screen resolution, update or re-install drivers, scan for virus/malware, fix registry with programs.

But nothing worked except re-install Windows. But this way is a bit annoying because I lost my legal key, if I re-install Windows I have to buy a new one or use the illegal Windows key.

Even if I re-install the Windows, it'll happen again after a few month operation.

This happen many times before with my Windows7, every time I re-install and every time it came back. So I upgrade to win 8 and now it happen again.

Some people told me that was a hard drive issue, but it's fixed after I re-install Windows, so I think it a Windows issue.

Comment: Detailed hardware specs would be nice nevertheless.

Comment: If you lost your key, use any key retrieval tool to extract it from the current installation.

Answer (score 0):

Ever piece of hardware and running software needs to be Sleep/Hibernation-compatible for it to work.

Things to try:

- Disconnect all peripherals except keyboard and mouse and try it again.
- If it still doesn't work, try a different (make and model) of keyboard and mouse.
- If that doesn't work, then try hibernating with no application programs open.
- If that doesn't work you need to disable all 3rd party start-ups and services and try again.

If hibernation works during any of these tests work then you've narrowed your suspect to a group (peripheral, software application, or start-up program/service).  One you've narrowed it down to hardware or software or services, try re-attaching/re-enabling one thing at a time in that group until you find the actual culprit.

For example I had similar problems with Vista, but it would come and go, seemingly randomly. I just lived with it and eventually upgraded to Windows 7. The same problem existed in Win7 as well (after a while), so I hunted it down.  Eventually determined it was a USB Guitar Hero guitar controller doing it, and it had evaded me because my girlfriend was plugging it in to use it every now and then (unbeknownst to me).